# Using DotnetCore Class Libraries in Multi Target Scenario

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net5

I have some problems to understand the portable class libraries and the new .NET Core System (RC2). My goal is to manage my code base in multiple solutions and to target Windows10, ASP.NET Core and .NET 4.6.1. Depending on the project, the targets might be different, e.g. my Utils Library with some methods like Guard.NotNull should target all three platforms. A MongoDB helper library must target ASP.NET Core and .NET 4.6.1 only.

I created a .NET Core Class Library with the following settings:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore": "5.0.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.4": {
      "imports": [ "uap10.0", "dnxcore50" ]
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to reference it from a Universal Class Library (where I have some of my controls) I get the following error:

```
Checking compatibility of packages on UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
ClassLibrary1 1.0.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
CodicePlastico 1.0.0 is not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
```

At the moment, I am really confused.

Comment: The portable classes libraries aren't used likes they did before. The new project type is called "Class Library (package)" and contains a project.json which has multiple targets. While old PCL only had a subset and produced **one** assembly that worked on all platforms, the new "Class Library (package)" creates multiple assemblies (one for each target)

Comment: I know, but I should be able to create a nuget package that I can use in multiple environments, isnt it?